# Groupby and Cumulative count in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I want to group by two columns and get their cumulative count. I tried looking for relevant code in the group ,couldn't find it, but got few hints based on what I have coded, but it is ending up with an error. Can this be solved?

```
ID  ABC   XYZ
 1    A  .512 
 2    A  .123
 3    B  .999 
 4    B  .999
 5    B  .999 
 6    C  .456 
 7    C  .456
 8    C  .888
 9    d  .888
10    d  .888
```

The output should be as below[Either ABC or XYZ has new value counter should be incremented].

```
ID  ABC   XYZ  GID
 1    A  .123    1
 2    A  .512    2
 3    B  .999    3
 4    B  .999    3
 5    B  .999    3
 6    C  .456    4
 7    C  .456    4
 8    C  .888    5
 9    d  .888    6
10    d  .888    6
```

The code is as below

```
DF=DF.sort(['ABC','XYZ'] ,ascending = [1,0]) 
DF['GID'] = DF.groupby('ABC','XYZ').cumcount()
```

But it is ending up with an Error:

> ValueError: No axis named XYZ for object type

Comment: Your second try should work. You just need to pass the column names in a list  `DF.groupby([ 'ABC','XYZ']).cumcount()`

Comment: Great,now issue solved. Thanks for saving time.

Answer (score 3):

I got the desired results like this.

```
c1 = df.ABC != DF.ABC.shift()
c2 = df.XYZ != DF.XYZ.shift()
DF['GID'] = (c1 | c2).cumsum()
DF
```

[image]

Comment: Superb!!The code worked as expected/provided in the sample data.
Thanks piRsquared also thanks for ayhan for solving the issue. 
One other query is I have column names as 'ABC Name' and 'XYZ Value'  which has space between the words, hence it is showing as invalid syntax. I tried putting single and Double quotes also [ ] and () but still it is not helping. Is there way to pass the column name same as above(but not renaming).